# PoolTimeoutException when connecting to Cassandra via Astyanax

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I am trying to connect to local cassandra using astyanax, but constantly getting  PoolTimeoutException. I am able to connect to cassandra using cli or hector client.
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

My code:

```
val context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
        .forCluster("cluster")
        .forKeyspace(keyspace)
        .withAstyanaxConfiguration(
                new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
                    .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE)
        )
        .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(
                new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("ConnPool")
                    .setPort(9160)
                    .setMaxConnsPerHost(1)
                    .setMaxBlockedThreadsPerHost(1)
                    .setSeeds("127.0.0.1:9160")
                    .setConnectTimeout(10000)
        )
        .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
        .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance())
    context.start()
    return context.getEntity()
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException: PoolTimeoutException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=10004(10004), attempts=1] Timed out waiting for connection
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$7.getNextBlock(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:652)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftAllRowsImpl$1.hasNext(ThriftAllRowsImpl.java:61)
at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(JavaConversions.scala:574)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JIteratorWrapper.foreach(JavaConversions.scala:573)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:73)
at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JIterableWrapper.foreach(JavaConversions.scala:587)
at  at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:76)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:30)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:60)
at Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException: PoolTimeoutException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=10004(10004), attempts=1] Timed out waiting for connection
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:201)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.borrowConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:158)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.borrowConnection(RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.java:60)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:50)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:229)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$7.getNextBlock(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:623)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another issue is if you slam data into one node and you have a threadpool of 50 and only 1 connection per host, you will get the same thing so you have to balance the number of threads/ host in certain situations as well.

Answer (score 2):

We were having this problem as well. For us, it turned out to be a version problem with libthrift. Version 0.7.0 worked. Version 0.6.1 did not. Check your classpath and see... Good luck.

-td

Comment: "tom d" nice catch, thanks! anyone who upgrades astyanax jar to v1.0.6 without maven, don't forget to upgrade libthrift to 0.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Trying to connect via the wrong port will also give this error.  See [this](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/issues/86) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/), For me it works installing this applications:

[Boost](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/os_x)
[libevent](http://libevent.org/)
[Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource)

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in the cassandra.yaml

1. Check the `rpc_address`
2. Check the  `rpc_port`
3. Set `start_rpc` to `true`